# Machine family N2 and GPUs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I was interested in trying the N2 CPU family of CPUs.

I tried creating a new instance using N2 CPU family - but no matter which Region/Zone I selected, the GPUs option remained ghosted (not selectable).

Is there a restriction on N2 CPUs to not allow for GPUs to be added?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus#restrictions)

> GPUs are currently only supported with general-purpose N1 machine types.

So....

Answer (score 0):

Google have moved the restrictions text to a new place.
New document link: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/about-gpus#restrictions